# Jar file dont work when i execute my "sh" File in linux consol

Tags: java, linux, selenium

When i try to execute to execute this line

```
bash -x ExecutionAuto.bat
```

I get an error from my Lib folder saying that one of the jars  isnt working properly.

```
../Demo_Automatisation/lib/SparseBitSet-1.2.jar: line 1: $'PK\003\004': command not found
../Demo_Automatisation/lib/SparseBitSet-1.2.jar: line 2: $'ؔ\220L': command not found
../Demo_Automatisation/lib/SparseBitSet-1.2.jar: line 8: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
��������0 6&»���2<��߽�{�i'���arseBitSet-1.2.jar: line 8: `��6)Ѐ*u)�����RP  �rN-p�đ�
                            �{�eB�M}i��Qa0�{}/�aHU�
'���xQXk)�Ћ.'?l3����A�I�|��0AİV���v�)s    ?���5N���V��v��hH�;"���~Gt  D��}|ȣ^�`�ܨ"r��d���}7��0t)y���{�W���
+ java org.testng.TestNG ../Demo_Automatisation/testng.xml
Error: Could not find or load main class org.testng.TestNG
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.testng.TestNG
```

I dont know if there is a probleme with the jar files since it works fine in Windows but in linux it doesnt work.

This is my .sh file:

```
export projectLocation=../Demo_Automatisation
cd $projectLocation
export CLASSPATH=$projectLocation/bin;$projectLocation/lib/*
java org.testng.TestNG $projectLocation/testng.xml
```

I just coppied what i found on the internet since i had a .bat file at first since i was using Windows does transferring from Windows to linux requieres that i do something to my jar files ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that the `;` in your classpath definition actually separates two commands so the `$projectLocation/lib/*` is interpreted as a new command, expands to the name of the jar file and the shell tries to execute the jar file as a shell script (which fails miserably). On Linux the separator for classpaths is `:` and not `;` (almost certainly for exactly this reason).

In other words: instead of

```
export CLASSPATH=$projectLocation/bin;$projectLocation/lib/*
```

you need

```
export CLASSPATH=$projectLocation/bin:$projectLocation/lib/*
```

As a bonus suggestion: the `/*` in the `CLASSPATH` should be interpreted by Java and *not* the shell, so it's better to actually quote the value:

```
export CLASSPATH="$projectLocation/bin:$projectLocation/lib/*"
```

Comment: would love to kiss you bro but dont know where you live god bless you

Comment: Thanks, I think we're all better off in a kiss-less scenario here ;-)